# Can I block android phones from my company wireless network?

Tags: networking, security, wifi

Network is password protected, all employees have access to password.  Company policy is only company approved and provided devices are allowed on network.   We can not tell who is logging in on unapproved devices, but it is > 100 people.

Thanks.

Comment: What wireless hardware do you use?

Answer (score 3):

This depends entirely on what wireless hardware you use. If you have something like [Cisco ISE](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps11640/index.html) tied into Cisco Wireless LAN Controllers or WiSMs then sure. Aruba and Meraki (recently purchased by Cisco) also have modules for this kind of thing.

If you just have a few random SOHO APs floating around, then no. You can't do something like this. You need an enterprise wireless solution for this sort of thing.